# File upload not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have created a file upload in PHP. the max file size is 5MB. I'm trying to upload a file which is 39 MB.

The file upload is working fine for all the files which are of 5MB or less than 5MB, it is even working fine with 30 MB file and returning ERROR: MAX file size limit exceeds. But only in this case 39MB it is returning the below error.

I'm getting below error.
[image]

```
    **action.php**

         <form class="w3-container " action='file_upload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
            <DIV id="file_name_div">  
            <label  for="file_name">Enter file name: </label><br>                       
            <input data-validation="filename" autocomplete="off" style="width:30%" class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey " type="text" name='file_name' id='file_name' autofocus /> 
<label  for="Role">Enter Role: </label><br>                       
            <input data-validation="role" style="width:30%" class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey " type="text" name='role' id='role' autofocus /> 
            </DIV>
            <br>  
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-info btn-md w3-blue"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reset</button> 
        </form>

****file_upload.php****

        <?php
        session_start();
        include_once 'config.php';
        $message  = '';
        $fileName = $_POST['file_name']; //LINE NO 6
        $role     = $_POST['role']; #role code //LINE NO 7
        $dir= "files/$role/"; #uploading file to selected role
        foreach ($_FILES as $filename => $filearray) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($filearray['tmp_name'])) {

            $fileLogicalName = $filearray['name'];

            $fileSize = (int) ($filearray['size'] / 1024);

            $filePhysicalName = pathinfo("$fileLogicalName"); //Return complete file name with extension 

            $filePhysicalName['filename']; //The arrray of pathinfo return only file name without extension


            if ($fileSize <= 5120) // 5mb/1024
                {
//file upload code
                }
    }
    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try add more size to the file limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1028M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','1028M');
ini_set('post_max_siz','1028M');
```